# this question is about plane vector.

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

[Plane Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCych.jpg)

I am kind of stuggling with this sentence(A is the point {1,0,1} and B is the image of A under reflection in π2) How to find out coordinate of B in order to work out the vector equation of line AB??

Comment: i have attached a photo about my question above

Answer (score 0):

Hint. ${\bf v}=(3,4,1)$ is a vector which is orthogonal to the plane. Therefore the line $AB$ is parallel to ${\bf v} $ and its vector equation is $P=A+t{\bf v}$.

Now you should be able to find $N$: intersect the plane and the line.